# creating a project on mingw under windows

Tags: c++, mingw

I am creating a project using mingw under windows. When run on another PC (without wingw in PATH, respectively), get errors, missing: libwinpthread-1.dll, libgcc_s_seh-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll. How can I build the project so that everything starts up normally?

Comment: Can you like statically, instead of dynamically? (I wouldn't know about the nuts-and-bolts of that, sorry).

Comment: Normally you just distribute those files with your executable. You can embed them into the executable with `-static`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
 ok, but there is a problem. For some reason, with the -static key, mingw lost the opencv2 that he had seen before. Is there an obvious solution? If not, then I'll close the question.

Comment: sry `like` -> `link` !

Comment: Can you explain more how you installed opencv and what mingw flavor are you using? At least in MSYS2, I don't see static opencv libraries, meaning they should still be linked dynamically despite `-static`.

Comment: sorry for the trouble, it looks like I have opencv in the standard directories, and opencv is also in the project folder (installed a long time ago), it seems like gcc didn’t understand how it dynamically pulled the library not from the project folder, now I’ll deal with the names of the connected libraries. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C++ program needs *runtime libraries* to run. They're usually not part of the program itself! So you'd need to ship these libraries alongside with your program (which is what most software does).

You can, for many things, however, also use "static linking", which means that the parts of the libraries used by your program are included in your program itself! The `-static` flag supplied to executable-generating step in your project will do that. If your program consists of but a single file, that would be `g++ -o test -static test.c` (your `g++` might be called `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` or so).

Answer (score 0):

If your distributed `.exe` file won't run because of missing `.dll` files that's because it is linked against those files and you need to distribute these files with your `.exe` file.

But actually there are 2 solutions to this problem:

- **Shared build** (= using `.dll` files): distribute the `.dll` files with your application. The best place to put the `.dll` files is in the same folder as the `.exe` file(s). You can use [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to figure out which `.dll` files your `.exe` file needs (and which `.dll` files those `.dll` files need etc.) or you can use the command line tool `copypedeps -r` from the [pedeps project](https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps) to copy your `.exe` file(s) along with any `.dll` files required.
- **Static build** (= everything rolled into the `.exe` file(s)): when building your `.exe` file(s) use the `--static` linker flag (and if needed also `-static-libgcc` and/or `-static-libstdc++`). This create a static `.exe` file, which means all the static libraries are rolled into the `.exe` file. This may make your `.exe` quite large (though you can try reducing its size with the `strip` command or the `-s` linker flag) and doesn't have the advantage of `.dll` files where common code is only distributed once. It may also cause longer loading times for your application, since everything is loaded at once.

Comment: ok, I added --static, now windows doesn't swear at mingw dll. But bass.dll and opencv 4.5.2 still don't want to link statically. How to fix it?

Comment: Do you have static builds of those libraries?